# Where do I put shared model and controller logic?

Tags: sails.js

I've just started using Sails and I have a couple models with the same method defined multiple times. Is there a way to share logic between models? Like having a "Base" model from which other models inherit behaviour?

Same question for controllers. Is there a way to setup an "ApplicationController" or a system of inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Yedhu, however You can also create defaults and extend using lodash

```
var = defaultModel = require('./<LOCATION OF DEFAULT MODEL DEFINITION>/defaultModel');

module.exports.models = _.merge({
// .. defign your model here like your normally would
}, defaultModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Sails JS, started just two months back.

Not particularly for Models or Controllers. But still shared logic can go to [Services](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Services). I use this when I need to access the same code from multiple places within the application.